# What is the word saying that you mistakenly paint outside the lines when you do a painting?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

My children are attending a painting class (not a drawing class).

They first draw an outline of a picture in pencil on a paper.

Then, they paint within the lines of the picture and try not to paint outside the lines using a paint brush.

Sometimes, they make a mistake and make the ink go outside the lines.

Is it correct for them to say "*I happened to **smear** ink outside the lines*"?

Should we use "**smear**" to say that weu mistakenly paint outside the lines when we do a painting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, we shouldn't. If you smear paint, or any other substance, you make a (usually) unwanted mark by rubbing your finger, sleeve etc. against it and making it spread like [this](https://www.colourbox.com/image/smear-paint-or-cream-image-5652091).

When you are painting, you *want* to make the paint spread, but if a bit goes in the wrong place you have *gone/painted/coloured outside the lines.*

Comment: You have also _strayed_ over the lines.

Answer (score 0):

When I was child and used coloring books, the word used to describe *coloring outside the lines* was **scribbling**.  I can't find a definition that says scribbling is *coloring outside the lines,* but that's how it was used back in my Crayola days.

This usage, of course, has very little meaning when applied to painting.  I don't think a painter can *scribble*.